# Can a COM object method return a pointer to another object?

Tags: methods, interface, com

Can the method of a COM object return a pointer to another object? I'm wondering if it's possible to call methods from the result of one interface to another.

For example:

`object.getA().getB().getC()`

I've been having trouble finding references for what data types are available to COM objects since "object", "method", and "interface" provide overriding results unrelated to COM. I think I may need to buy some books to get a clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Look at the Microsoft Office interfaces.

Sort of the base object of Excel or Word is Application. With namespaces it may be Excel.Application or Word.Application.

Whether it is Excel or Word, they both have Application methods/properties that return other objects.

For Excel, Application.Workbooks returns an object that is a collection of Workbook(s). With this object you can iterate the open documents for the application. And, within each Workbook is a Worksheets collection which allows you to iterate through each Worksheet in the Workbook. The Worksheet has a Cells collection which allows you to get individual or ranges of cells in the Worksheet. The Application has an ActiveWorkbook property which returns the Workbook that has the current focus.

For Word, Application.Documents returns an object that is a collection of Document(s). You can iterate the open documents with this collection and get a particular Document. The Document has a Paragraphs collection. The Application has an ActiveDocument object to get the Word document in the foreground.

Many (or most) of the objects have an "Application" property which returns the Application the object belongs to.  Many (or most) have a "Parent" property which returns a context sensitive parent.

All these properties/methods returning other objects is what makes the Office automation model so powerful.  Imagine how weak it would be if it only returned strings or numbers.

```
MsgBox "This instance of Word has " & Application.Documents.Count " documents open."

Dim doc as Document
Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
MsgBox doc.Name & " has " doc.Paragraphs.Count & " paragraphs"
```

The above isn't powerful, but imagine using the object model to create a document on the fly and even to mail it. Or, to have a mailing list, and take a document and substitute a section of text with names or addresses and e-mailing the document individually to each person.